# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\log(n) + 2n \log(4n + 2) - \sum_{k = 1}^{2n} (-1)^k (2k+1)\log(2k+1)\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, logarithms, infinite-product

I am trying to show that the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\log(n) + 2n \log(4n+2) - \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k (2k+1) \log(2k + 1)\right] = \frac{2G}{\pi} - \log(4)$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant.

My attempt was to turn the partial sum into a product:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^n (2k+1) \log(2k + 1)
&= \log\left(\prod_{k=1}^{2n}(2k+1)^{(-1)^k(2k+1)} \right).
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a_n := \prod_{k=1}^{2n}(2k+1)^{(-1)^k(2k+1)}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a_n 
&= \frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} (4k+1)^{(4k+1)}\right)^2}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n} (2k+1)^{(2k+1)}} \\
&=\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} (4k+1)^{(4k+1)}\right)^2}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n} (2k+1)^{(2k+1)}} \cdot \frac{4^{n (2 n+1)} (H(2 n))^2}{\prod_{k = 1}^{2n} (2n)^{2n}} \quad \quad \Big[H(n) = \text{the hyperfactorial} \Big]\\
&= \frac{4^{n (2 n+1)} (H(2 n))^2}{H(4n+1)}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} (4k+1)^{(4k+1)}\right)^2.
\end{align*}

Another attempt, I considered using the following definition of the gamma function
$$\Gamma(x + 1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^x}{\prod_{k = 1}^n \left(1 + \frac{x}{k} \right)},$$
but I was unable to fund any helpful algebraic moves. I also considered using Abel's summation formula to simplify the partial sum down to a closed form, but quickly realized it was not helpful. From here, I was unable to find a closed form.

I also found this paper that I believe may be relevant to this problem. [A note on products involving ζ(3) and Catalan’s constant](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6247v3.pdf). Are there any algebraic moves that can be done using the gamma function's infinite product representation to derive the result? Is it possible there is an asymptotic formula that can be substituted in to evaluate this limit? Is there a better way to evaluate this limit? If so, what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I derive an asymptotic expansion with explicit error bound for the sum in question. Employing the [Euler–Boole summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Boole_summation) with $f(x) = 2x\log (2x)$, $h = \frac{1}{2}$, $n=2n+1$, $a=1$ and $m=2$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (2k + 1)\log (2k + 1)} = \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) - \log 2 + \int_1^{2n + 1} {\frac{1}{x}\widetilde E_1 \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x} 
\\ & = \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) - \log 2 + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{x}\widetilde E_1 \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x}  - \int_{2n + 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{x}\widetilde E_1 \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x} .
\end{align*}
The improper integrals are convergent due to the Dirichlet criteria, and thus the second integral tends to $0$ as $n\to +\infty$. The value of the first integral may be obtained via Fourier expansion:
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{x}\widetilde E_1 \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x}  & = \log 2 + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{x}\widetilde E_1 \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x} \\ & = \log 2 - \frac{4}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sin ((2k + 1)\pi x)}}{x}{\rm d}x} } 
\\ & = \log 2 - \frac{2}{\pi }\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}}  = \log 2 - \frac{{2G}}{\pi },
\end{align*}
where $G$ is Catalan's constant. Accordingly,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (2k + 1)\log (2k + 1)}  = \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) - \frac{{2G}}{\pi } + o(1)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. If we use the Euler–Boole summation formula with the same input but with $m=2m+1$ and note that odd Euler polynomials vanish at $h=\frac{1}{2}$, we find
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (2k + 1)\log (2k + 1)} & = \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) + C_m  + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m} {\frac{{E_{2k} }}{{(2k)!2^{2k} }}f^{(2k)} (2n + 1)} \\ & \quad\, - \frac{1}{{2(2m)!}}\int_{2n + 1}^{ + \infty } {f^{(2m+1)} (x)\widetilde E_{2m} \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x} 
\\ & =\frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) + C_m  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m} {\frac{{E_{2k} }}{{4k(2k - 1)}}\frac{1}{{(4n + 2)^{2k - 1} }}} \\ & \quad\,  + \frac{1}{{2m}}\int_{2n + 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{x^{2m} }}\widetilde E_{2m}\! \left( {\tfrac{1}{2} - x} \right){\rm d}x} 
\end{align*}
with some constant $C_m$ coming from the terms of the summation formula that do not depend on $n$. The last integral clearly converges to $0$ as $n\to +\infty$, hence, by our previous result, we must have $C_m =- \frac{{2G}}{\pi }$ for all $m$. We now note that
$$
\frac{1}{{2m}}\int_{2n + 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{x^{2m} }}\widetilde E_{2m}\! \left( {\tfrac{1}{2}- x} \right){\rm d}x}  =  - \frac{1}{{2m}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{(t + 2n + 1)^{2m} }}\widetilde E_{2m}\! \left( {\tfrac{1}{2}- t} \right){\rm d}t} 
$$
and
$$
\frac{{E_{2m} }}{{4m(2m - 1)}}\frac{1}{{(4n + 2)^{2m - 1} }} = \frac{1}{{2m}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{2^{ - 2m} E_{2m} }}{{(t + 2n + 1)^{2m} }}{\rm d}t}, 
$$
i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (2k + 1)\log (2k + 1)} = \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) - \frac{{2G}}{\pi } & + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m-1} {\frac{{E_{2k} }}{{4k(2k - 1)}}\frac{1}{{(4n + 2)^{2k - 1} }}} \\ & +R_m(n)
\end{align*}
with
$$
R_m(n)=\frac{1}{{2m}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{2^{ - 2m} E_{2m}  - \widetilde E_{2m} (1/2 - t)}}{{(t + 2n + 1)^{2m} }}{\rm d}t} .
$$
[Since](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.9.E3)
$$
\left| {2^{ - 2m} E_{2m}  - \widetilde E_{2m} (1/2 - t)} \right| \le 2^{ - 2m} \left| {E_{2m} } \right| + \sup _{0<x<1/2} \left| {E_{2m} (x)} \right| \le 2 \cdot 2^{ - 2m} \left| {E_{2m} } \right|,
$$
we find that
$$
|R_m (n)| \le 2 \cdot \frac{{\left| {E_{2m} } \right|}}{{4m(2m - 1)}}\frac{1}{{(4n + 2)^{2m - 1} }}.
$$
Thus, in summary,
\begin{multline*}\boxed{
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (2k + 1)\log (2k + 1)} = \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) - \frac{{2G}}{\pi } + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m-1} {\frac{{E_{2k} }}{{4k(2k - 1)}}\frac{1}{{(4n + 2)^{2k - 1} }}} +R_m(n)}
\end{multline*}
for any $n\ge 1$, $m\ge 1$, with
$$\boxed{
|R_m (n)| \le 2 \cdot \frac{{\left| {E_{2m} } \right|}}{{4m(2m - 1)}}\frac{1}{{(4n + 2)^{2m - 1} }}.}
$$
I expect that with more work, the factor $2$ in the error bound can be removed and it can be shown that $R_m(n)$ has the same sign as the first omitted term.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have a bit of trouble why you went on to let $m = 2m + 1$. It seems like you already had the asymptotic formula before. Perhaps I am missing some detail?

Comment: To obtain the correction terms you were interested in.

Comment: I see thank you so much @Gary

Comment: @Gary Thank you for you wonderful general solution. In my humble opinion, it is important to study the problem as deep as possible - to disclose the inherent symmetry and the infinite beauty of mathematics

Comment: @ QuodEratDemon, in my opinion, this solution addresses the problem in the most deep and professional way and, therefore, is the best.

Comment: @Gary out of curiosity, would Euler-Maclaurin summation work here too?

Comment: @QuodEratDemon In principle it would by writing your sum as the difference of sums over even and odd terms and then applying the Euler–Maclaurin formula to both sums separately.

Answer (score 3):

Switching $n\to2n$ for the convenience, we have to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\ln\frac{n}{2}+n\ln(2n+2)-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(2k+1)\ln(2k+1)\Big)=\frac{2G}{\pi}-2\ln2\quad (n\,\text{is even})$$
or, considering the asymptotics of the sum, to prove that
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(2k+1)\ln(2k+1)=n\ln n+n\ln2+\ln n+\ln2+1-\frac{2G}{\pi}+o(1)$$
Using the Frullani integral and performing summation, we can present the sum in the form (for even $n$)
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(2k+1)\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(2k+1)t}}{t}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\left(ne^{-t}+\frac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{2t}}+\frac{2e^t}{(1+e^{2t})^2}-\frac{(2n+1)e^{-(2n+1)t}}{1+e^{2t}}-\frac{2e^{-(2n-1)t}}{(1+e^{2t})^2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}$$
For the convenience of operation with every term separately, we consider a regularized integral (where $\epsilon$ is small but finite):
$$S_\epsilon(n)=\int_0^\infty\Big(...\Big)\frac{dt}{t^{1-\epsilon}}=S_0+S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4\tag{0}$$
Then
$$S_0=n\int_0^\infty t^{\epsilon-1}e^{-t}dt=n\,\Gamma(\epsilon)\tag{1}$$
$$S_3=-(2n+1)\int_0^\infty t^{\epsilon-1}\frac{e^{-(2n+1)t}}{1+e^{2t}}dt$$
Making the substitution $t=\frac{x}{2n+1}$ and keeping only non-zero terms at $n\to\infty$
$$S_3=-\frac{(2n+1)^{1-\epsilon}}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}x^{\epsilon-1}}{1+\frac{x}{2n+1}}dx+o(1)$$
$$=-n\Gamma(\epsilon)-\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon)}{2}+n\ln(2n)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2n)+1+o(1)\tag{2}$$
In the same way we evaluate $S_4$:
$$S_4=-\int_0^\infty\frac{2e^{-(2n-1)t}}{(1+e^{2t})^2}t^{\epsilon-1}dt=-\,\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2n)+o(1)\tag{3}$$
Next, let's consider
$$S_1+S_2-\Gamma(\epsilon)=\int_0^\infty\Big(\frac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{2t}}+\frac{2e^2}{(1+e^{2t})^2}-e^{-t}\Big)t^{\epsilon-1}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^t-e^{3t}}{(1+e^{2t})^2}t^{\epsilon-1}dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^2t}t^{\epsilon-1}dt$$
We see that this espression is regular at $\epsilon\to0$; therefore, we can put $\epsilon=0$ and consider
$$S_1+S_2-\Gamma(\epsilon)\to-\,\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sinh t}{t\cosh^2t}dt=-\frac{2\beta(2)}{\pi}=-\frac{2G}{\pi}\tag{4}$$
Probably, the easiest way of the evaluation is integration in the complex plane, closing the contour in the upper half-plane and evaluating residues at $t=\pi ik+\frac{\pi i}{2}, k=0,1,2...\,$ Another way is integration by part and usage of the analytical continuation and functional equation for [Dirichlet beta-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

Putting (1)-(4) into (0) we see that all diverging at $\epsilon\to 0$ terms cancel, and we are left with
$$\boxed{\,\,S(n)=n\ln(2n)+\ln(2n)+1-\frac{2G}{\pi}+o(1)\,\,}$$
The limit follows.

Comment: @Svyatoslav You have to sum up until $2n$ in the defintion of $S(n)$. Your $S(n)$ alternates in sign with respect to $n$.

Comment: Note also that for the corrected sum, $4n+2$ is a more natural asymptotic parameter: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (2k + 1)\log (2k + 1)}  \sim \frac{1}{2}(4n + 2)\log (4n + 2) - \frac{{2G}}{\pi } - \frac{1}{{4(4n + 2)}} + \frac{5}{{24(4n + 2)^3 }} -  \ldots 
$$ as $n\to +\infty$. This may be inferred from the Euler–Boole summation formula.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you so much for your solution! I am still a bit confused about how you derived the asymptotics for $S_3$ and $S_4$. I tried turning $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{x}{2n+1}}$ and switch the order of summation and integration. Would you be able to provide more detail? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gary May I ask how you got the trailing terms $$- \frac{1}{4(4n+2)} + \frac{5}{24(4n+2)^3} - \ldots$$ I am not really well-versed in deriving asymptotics or the Euler-Boole summation formula.

Comment: @QuodEratDemon I can prepare a separate answer with details on this if that is of interest for you.

Comment: @Gary That would be of interest for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gary, thank you for you comment! Strictly speaking, you are right. I mentioned that $n$ is even in my calculation - I just tried to find a shortcut to the answer (non-vanishing terms at $n\to\infty$). Your answer gives the deep insight into the symmetry of the asymptotic, and I'm looking forward to study, as usual, your solution :)

Comment: @QuodEratDemon, we have
$$\int_0^\infty t^{\epsilon-1}\frac{e^{-(2n+1)t}}{1+e^{2t}}dt\overset{t=\frac{x}{2n+1}}{=}\Big(\frac{1}{2n+1}\Big)^\epsilon\int_0^\infty x^{\epsilon-1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{\frac{2x}{2n+1}}}dx$$
As we have $e^{-x}$ in the nominator, with the accuracy up to exponentially small terms we can decompose the exponent in the denominator:
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{2x}{2n+1}}}=\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{x}{2n+1}+...)}=\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{x}{2n+1}+..\Big)$$ 
and then integrate term by term.

Comment: @Svyatoslav So would all that remain is to evaluate this expression $$-\frac{(2n+1)^{1-\epsilon}}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{\epsilon-1} \left(1 - \frac{x}{2n+1} \right)dx+o(1)
$$

Comment: Yes, this is correct. To evaluate this expression and keep only non-vanishing terms (at $n\to\infty$)

Comment: @Svyatoslav I evaluated the integral to be $$-\frac{(2n+1)^{1-\epsilon}}{2}\left(\Gamma (\epsilon )-\frac{\epsilon  \Gamma (\epsilon )}{2 n+1}\right).$$ Am I missing some detail here?

Comment: This is correct. $\epsilon\Gamma(\epsilon)=\Gamma(1+\epsilon)\to 1$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. And $(2n+1)^{1-\epsilon}\Gamma(\epsilon)\to (2n+1)(1-\epsilon\ln(2n+1))\Gamma(\epsilon)\to (2n+1)(\Gamma(\epsilon)-\ln(2n+1)\Gamma(1+\epsilon))$